# How can I convert input from a JTextField into a Date?

Tags: java, swing, date, parsing

I'm trying to combine two programs to create a clock and a timer that counts down until a time the user gives in a `JTextField` (Swing). When I run the programs separately, it seems to work, but when I combine them, I run into some issues translating the `JTextField` into a `Date`.

I tried converting the `JTextField` into a `String` first and then parsing it as a date, but when I do this I get `unparsable date (yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss a)`.  I'm aware that the code still has a lot of work to do and is pretty messy but I would appreciate any help.  Here's the part of my code containing the issue:

```
JLabel time = new JLabel("Time: ", JLabel.RIGHT);
final JTextField gameDate = new JTextField("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", 21);
DateFormat apiFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
apiFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
String D = gameDate.getText();
Date dateOfGame = apiFormat.parse(D);
long diff = new Date().getTime() - dateOfGame.getTime();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you debug the application and tell us what the string contains before the error is thrown?

Comment: If you still have a lot of work to do anyway, then I suggest to use `java.time.*` instead of `java.util.Date` for any temporal operations and representations.

Comment: Try to print on console which value has `D` before doing the parse (seems that you are trying to get it from a textfield). I expect all this code block isn't on the same function (because initializing the JTextfield with `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` will obviously throw you a parseException). Also you can have this exception if you run parse before allowing the user enter the date.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Consider a different approach (easier for the user & you) 1) SpinnerDateModel dateModel = new SpinnerDateModel(..);` 2) `JSpinner dateSpinner = new JSpinner(dateModel);` 3) (some time later in the code when the value changes) `Date date = dateModel.getDate(); ..`

Comment: You may want to use a date picker and a time picker rather then a text field. While I don’t think Swing has those parts built in, there are some to choose from out there, use your search engine.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a text field containing `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`, then immediately taking the content out of it and trying to parse it as a date-time. Instead you need to let the user enter a date and time into the field before trying to parse.

You would usually have the user press an OK button or the like, and when s/he does that, then proceed with calling `getText()` to get the date and time entered.

That said, you shouldn’t use `Date`, `TimeZone` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those old classes have design problems, the last in particular is notoriously troublesome, and all are long outdated. Instead use `LocalDateTime`, `ZoneId` and `DateTimeFormatter` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Also don’t rely on a three-letter time zone abbreviation like `EST`. While `TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST")` is probably deterministic, I don’t know by heart whether it gives you `America/New_York` or UTC-05:00, and other readers won’t know either. To add to the confusion, EST may also mean Australian Eastern Standard Time, and there may be yet other interpretations. So use `America/New_York` if that’s what you intend.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.